# GraphQL Query - Conditional where condition execution

Tags: reactjs, graphql, where-clause, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have following query:

```
query GET_APM_BY_RG($subscriptionName: [String!], $resourceGroupName: [String!], $userAzureId: String!) {
  dashboardFilters(
    findoptions: {
      distinct: ["apm"]
      select: { apm: true }
      where: {
        subscription: { 
          subscriptionName : { in: $subscriptionName}
          resourceGroupName: { in: $resourceGroupName } }
        requestors: { some: { requestorId: $userAzureId } }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

and I want the subscriptionName condition of the where only apply conditionally. When $subscriptionName is provided it should be a condition, otherwise it should not apply at all.

I tried using directives:

```
query GET_APM_BY_RG($subscriptionName: [String!], $resourceGroupName: [String!], $userAzureId: String!) {
  dashboardFilters(
    findoptions: {
      distinct: ["apm"]
      select: { apm: true }
      where: {
        subscription: { 
          subscriptionName : { in: $subscriptionName} @include(if: $subscriptionName)
          resourceGroupName: { in: $resourceGroupName } }
        requestors: { some: { requestorId: $userAzureId } }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Though, if I use GraphQL dirctives(@include and @skip) - it is erroring out:

> Above query is giving an error: Uncaught GraphQLError: Syntax Error:
> Expected Name, found "@".

Directives only works for field names but how to achieve this for conditional where condition in GraphQL?

Also tried to embed the entire where clause into a variable.

```
query GET_APM_BY_RG(
  $subscriptionName: [String!]
  $resourceGroupName: [String!]
  $userAzureId: String!
  $whereClause: QueryEventInput!
) {
  dashboardFilters(
    findoptions: {
      distinct: ["apm"]
      select: { apm: true }
      where: $whereClause
    }
  )
}
```

This gives following error:

> Unknown type "QueryEventInput".